# Displaying help text after clicking the pushbutton and lineedit

Tags: qt4

I have a pushbutton and a lineedit , and what i want is , when i click that pushbutton or lineedit  a help text(the purpose of that component) shall be shown besides the respective component.
Please give reply soon , i need it urgently ..
Thankx in advance ..

Comment: Also, what exactly do you mean with 'besides the respective component'? Like a mouseover text balloon, or in a widget in the same window?

Comment: Thankx for your suggestion brother ...ya mouseover text ballon ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
connect(ui->pushButton,SIGNAL(pressed()),this,SLOT(YourPrivateSlot()));

void YourPrivateSlot()
{
QPalette palette(QColor(0,0,0,0));
QToolTip::setPalette(palette);
QToolTip::showText(QPoint(Parentwidgetofpushbutton->x() + pushButton->x(),
Parentwidgetofpushbutton->y() + pushButton->y()) ,"Your Message" ,
pushButton,QRect(20,20,50,50));
}
```

This will show a text balloon just above pushbutton with text color black on yellow background(by default) when pushbutton is pressed.You can adjust the position of balloon as you wish by changing position accordingly.